# Can you enforce a typealias in swift

Tags: swift, types

I am trying to enforce a simple type backed by an `Int` does not get mixed up with other `Int`s.

Say you have the following typealiases :

```
typealias EnemyId = Int
typealias WeaponId = Int
```

I would like the following to have a compiler error:

```
var enemy: EnemyId = EnemyId("1")
enemy = WeaponId("1") // this should fail
```

The line I want to fail, should fail, because the two types (EnemyId and WeaponId) are different types.

What would be the nicest, cleanest way of achieving this?

**UPDATE**

After reviewing the answers and comments, I wanted to add what I came up with using enums:

```
enum Enemy {
    case id(Int)
    var id: Int {
        switch self {
        case .id(let i):
            return i
        }
    }
}
let enemy = Enemy.id(1)
print("enemy: \(enemy.id)")
```

Currently Mattt's answer is much shorter and more in line with what you expect in Swift.

**UPDATE #2**

I do not yet have access to swift 4.1 so I had to do the following:

```
  struct EnemyId : Hashable {
    private let value: Int

    init(_ value: Int) {
      self.value = value
    }

    init?(_ string:String) {
      guard let value = Int(string) else { return nil }
      self.init(value)
    }

    static func ==(_ lhs: EnemyId, _ rhs: EnemyId) -> Bool {
      return lhs.value == rhs.value
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
      return value.hashValue
    }
  }
```

It however turned out to add a couple of hundreds of milliseconds to my parsing, therefore I had to revert to the typealias, but it was very close to what I wanted.

Comment: This looks to something an `enum` would be more useful for.  That way, the compiler prevents you from accidental conversions like these, you never have to worry about an invalid enemy or weapon type, and you can refer to values using `Weapon.sword` (or even `.sword` in most cases) instead of having to declare constants like `WEAPON_SWORD`.

Comment: @NobodyNada I toyed with enums too, but predefining every possible ID is overkill. At least I was unable to come to a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift doesn't (yet?) have the concept of `newtype` - basically an opaque type backstored with the same values as the original type.

What you could do, is to use 1-field structs that wrap the original type. 1-field structs have no performance penalty while giving you a distinct type to work with, carrying more semantical value ( thanks @RobNapier for the great tip regarding `Hashable`):

```
struct EnemyId: Hashable {
    private let value: Int

    init(_ value: Int) { self.value = value }

    static func ==(_ lhs: EnemyId, _ rhs: EnemyId) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value == rhs.value
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return value.hashValue
    }
}

struct WeaponId: Hashable {
    private let value: Int

    init(_ value: Int) { self.value = value }

    static func ==(_ lhs: WeaponId, _ rhs: WeaponId) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value == rhs.value
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return value.hashValue
    }
}
```

Types like this can be used in many places as an `Int` would do, while being different. Of course you could add more protocols conformance, based on the needs.

Comment: In most cases, rather than dereferencing the value, it's better to provide the functionality directly on the struct. In many cases, `value` should be treated as an internal implementation detail. (If you need a lot of methods, it does become a little tedious, but you get a lot more value. Hopefully we'll eventually get a solution where you can pass-through specific protocols. (There are some headaches about this related to associated types, but we can hope.)

Comment: Not to detract from this answer (which is exactly right IMO), but I added some code to show how this can be done more generally if you have a bunch of these (like I often do).

Comment: Actually in Swift 4.1 this becomes _way_ easier. You just conform to Hashable, and both `hashValue` and `==` simply spring to life full-formed! You only need the `init`, and you can omit that too if you don't mind saying `value:` in the initializer.

Comment: @Cristik I like the `newtype` concept, maybe it should be added to swift. It is exactly what I am looking for. :)

Answer (score 7):

Note that in Swift 4.1 wrapper structs like Rob and Cristik are suggesting become trivial to write, because when you declare adoption of Hashable, you get *automatically synthesized implementations* of `hashValue` and `==` behind the scenes.

Thus, for your purposes, it might be sufficient to write:

```
struct EnemyId: Hashable {
    let value: Int
}
struct WeaponId: Hashable {
    let value: Int
}
```

You get the memberwise initializer `init(value:)` plus `==` plus `hashValue` "for free" in both cases.

Comment: With the mention that the memberwise initializer is `internal`, thus won't be available if the struct is defined in another module.

Comment: @Cristik Thanks, I didn't know that (though I remember there was something about initializers and other modules in the 4.1 notes).

Answer (score 2):

Cristik is completely correct IMO. If you only have a few of these, you can just hand-code the protocols, but it can get a bit tedious to implement `Equatable` half-a-dozen times in exactly the same way. If that happens to you, you can make this kind of thing much more automatic with a protocol like this one:

```
protocol NumberConvertible: CustomStringConvertible, Comparable {
    init(number: NSNumber)
    var numberValue: NSNumber { get }
}

// CustomStringConvertible
extension NumberConvertible {
    var description: String { return numberValue.description }
}

// Comparable
func == <N: NumberConvertible>(lhs: N, rhs: N) -> Bool {
    return lhs.numberValue == rhs.numberValue
}

func < <N: NumberConvertible>(lhs: N, rhs: N) -> Bool {
    return lhs.numberValue.int64Value < rhs.numberValue.int64Value
}
```

This is just part of one I happen to have handy that used `NSNumber` to interop more easily with Core Data. Obviously you can build a similar `IntConvertible` that would work the same way without needing `NSNumber`. But this kind of protocol/extension really makes the one-field struct ("type lifting") much more palatable. I use these for IDs all over the place, exactly as you're describing.

As a side note: these are typically very cheap in Swift. Structs have no storage overhead, so the memory usage for a struct containing an Int is just the Int. With whole-module optimization, Swift can often inline much of the indirection as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a little wrapper struct:

```
struct EnemyID {
    let value: Int

    init?(_ value: String) {
        guard let intValue = Int(value) else { return nil }
        self.value = intValue
    }
}
```

...and the same for `WeaponID`.

Answer (score 1):

Until introduction of a `newtype` you can use something like this:

```
struct IntID<T> {
    var value: Int
}
...
typealias EnemyID = IntID<Enemy>
typealias WeaponID = IntID<Weapon>
...

let enemyID = EnemyID(value: 1)
let weaponID = WeaponID(value: 1)
```

In this case it will not allow you to make an order mistake when calling a function like `blah` in this example:

```
func blah(enemyID: EnemyID, weaponID: WeaponID) {...}
...
blah(enemyID: enemyID, weaponID: weaponID) //works
blah(enemyID: weaponID, weaponID: enemyID) //doesn't
```

On top of that you can add conformance to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`

```
extension IntID: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

which will allow you to do the following:

```
let enemyId: EnemyID = 2
let weaponID: WeaponID = 4

blah(enemyID: enemyID, weaponID: weaponID)
blah(enemyID: 6, weaponID: 7)
// but this one will not compile
let intValue = 42
blah(enemyID: intValue, weaponID: intValue)
```